# Does Amplify SDK support PKCE out of the box for your React site?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am working on a web app built with the AWS Amplify framework and react.  The app will use a Cognito Hosted UI to log in its users, preferably using the Authorization Code Grant with PKCE flow.

Does anybody know if the Amplify SDK supports this flow out of the box?  I know it supports the Authorization Code Grant part, but I am mostly wondering if it implements the PKCE extension too.

My apologies if this info was in the docs, and I just missed it. Thank you for your advise!

Answer (score 0):

yes it does. PKCE will be used automatically when using the HostedUI and Amplify. I am not aware of this being in the docs but the simple answer is yes :)

Comment: Great news, and thank you for answering my question!

Comment: What's your source? How can I confirm it?

Comment: https://github.com/CiaranCallaghan94/Cognito-SDK-Examples/tree/master/amplify-react

Test it out yourself. It's a couple of lines but the PKCE values are present in the request generated from Amplify and throughout the flow.

Authorize request contains:
code_challenge_method
code_challenge

The PKCE values I am referring to are stated here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html

Comment: Does it have to be the Hosted UI? What about if I just use Amplify's Auth library, does it include PKCE?

Comment: PKCE is used when interacting with the HostedUI/Oauth endpoints. So if you are using the hosted UI or integrating with an external IDP (via the Oauth endpoints) then yes. If you are just simply authenticating with the UserPool via the native API (initiate_auth api call) then no as this is not an OAuth flow.

Comment: @Callo

Stupid question: Does this mean we should almost always use hosted-ui as it uses pkce and more secure than native api?

Comment: @Sun PKCE is for OAuth Flows. So when interacting with the OAuth endpoints via the Hosted UI, it is best to use PKCE. However, the standard Cognito API is not part of an OAuth flow so there is no need for PKCE. PKCE is to help keep the integrity of the code exchange. The standard API calls do not require this code exchange. AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [Amplify-JS](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js), then yes, this uses PKCE for the code grant flow. You can see that in the [Oauth.ts](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/b5d424372d382e638bd58844ec34c512026cae02/packages/auth/src/OAuth/OAuth.ts) open source file. It also uses a `state` variable for further protection. I encourage you to inspect the file yourself and see what it's doing.

I'll just add some highlights, for the signin case.

Sign in starts here:

```
public oauthSignIn
```

Generates a random state variable which can be used to verify responses from Cognito are authentic (and presumably defend against CSRF as mentioned [here](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-secure-the-cognito-login-flow-with-a-state-nonce-and-pkce/#defense)):

```
const generatedState = this._generateState(32);
```

A code verifier is created:

```
const pkce_key = this._generateRandom(128);
```

A code challenge is created from the verifier (the base-64-URL encoding of the SHA256 of the verifier):

```
const code_challenge = this._generateChallenge(pkce_key);
```

If the response type is code, then the code challenge & the code challenge method are sent over as URL query params to Cognito:

```
...(responseType === 'code' ? { code_challenge } : {}),
...(responseType === 'code' ? { code_challenge_method } : {}),
```

When Cognito redirects back to the webpage that initiated the flow, the `_handleCodeFlow` method kicks off. We can see the code verifier pulled from the [oAuthStorage](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/b5d424372d382e638bd58844ec34c512026cae02/packages/auth/src/OAuth/oauthStorage.ts) if it exists and sent to Cognito for code exhange.